# Constant Error When Entering the "Deploy" Phase of my CodePipeline with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to create a CI pipeline with Github, AWS CodeBuild, CodePipelines, and CodeDeploy. I continually get the error As shopwn below

[image: error code here]

I have my s3 bucket that holds my artifacts that I want to be pushed on an "allow all" policy for troubleshooting purposes and I have full permissions to the github repo I am pulling from. The "Release Change" on pipelines always fails at the deploy phase shown by image 1 below. It also fails relatively quickly if that helps. For context I am trying to create CI to just one ec2 atm and that ec2 has the deploy agent running on it and is working. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: internal error means there is configuration issue on the deploy stage, please use aws codepipeline get-pipeline api call to see if the deployment group name and application name does not have any naming issue and check all the possible config on deploy stage

Comment: Such error will be very difficult to troubleshoot without complete information. Check the CloudTrail during the time of action execution for any errors that may point to the issue.

Comment: any luck? Having the same problem